# How to search order using database frontend short code WordPress

Tags: php, shortcode, database, search

I do not have a lot of coding knowledge. How do I add a WordPress searching database shortcode to the frontend using the metavalue as if I were to search for "demo", the metavalue(named as serial) will display the database that has the word "demo". The furthest I can go is displaying all the values from selecting the table. I do not plan on using any plugins.

```
 function wpb_demo_shortcode() {
global $wpdb;


$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, o.`order_item_name`, om.`meta_value` as 'bcs', 
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') as 'certificate',
 (select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') as 'serial'
 FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` as o,
`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` as om,
`wp_postmeta` as pm
WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
om.`meta_key` = 'bcs'
AND 
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') IS NOT null
 AND  
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') IS NOT null
");



$serial = (isset( $_GET['$serial'] )) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['$serial']) : '';
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="fname">Serial number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="$serial" name="$serial"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$enteredSerial = $_GET['$serial'];

ob_start();
 echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<th>Order ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
    echo '<th>BCS</th>';
    echo '<th>Serial</th>';
    echo '<th>Certificate</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach( $results as $result ){

        // Html display
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->order_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->order_item_name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->bcs . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->serial . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->certificate . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}



add_shortcode('greeting', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

I have added a placeholder (If I am right) for the metavalue. The pic below will show how the front end should look like

[image: Frontend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is more simple than I thought

```
function wpb_demo_shortcode() {
global $wpdb;


$results = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, o.`order_item_name`, om.`meta_value` as 'bcs', 
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') as 'certificate',
 (select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') as 'serial'
 FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` as o,
`wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` as om,
`wp_postmeta` as pm
WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
om.`meta_key` = 'bcs'
AND 
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
 o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') IS NOT null
 AND  
(select  pm.`meta_value`
 from 
 `wp_postmeta` as pm
 WHERE
o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
AND
pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
AND
 pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') IS NOT null
");



$serial = (isset( $_GET['$serial'] )) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['$serial']) : '';

?>
<form action="" method="get">
  <label for="fname">Serial number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="$serial" name="$serial" minlength="3"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$enteredSerial = $_GET['$serial'];
echo $enteredSerial;

if(!empty($enteredSerial))
{
ob_start();
 echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<th>Order ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
    echo '<th>BCS</th>';
    echo '<th>Serial</th>';
    echo '<th>Certificate</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach( $results as $result ){
        if (strpos($result->serial, $enteredSerial) !== false)
        {// Html display
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->order_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->order_item_name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->bcs . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->serial . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->certificate . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
    }

    echo '</table>';
}


}


add_shortcode('greeting', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code it may help you and sure that your sql query is correct then it will be work properly.

```
function wpb_demo_shortcode() {
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
            $wpdb->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id, o.`order_item_name`, om.`meta_value` 
                as 'bcs', (select  pm.`meta_value` from `wp_postmeta` 
                as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id 
                AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id 
                AND pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') 
                as 'certificate', (select  pm.`meta_value` from  `wp_postmeta` 
                as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id 
                AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id 
                AND pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') 
                as 'serial' FROM `wp_woocommerce_order_items` 
                as o, `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` 
                as om, `wp_postmeta` 
                as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id 
                AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
                AND om.`meta_key` = 'bcs'
                AND (select  pm.`meta_value` from `wp_postmeta` 
                as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
                AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
                AND pm.`meta_key` = '2-certificate') IS NOT null
                AND (select  pm.`meta_value` from `wp_postmeta` as pm WHERE o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
                AND pm.`post_id` = o.order_id
                AND pm.`meta_key` = '3-serial') IS NOT null") 
            );

$serial = (isset( $_GET['$serial'] )) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['$serial']) : '';
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="fname">Serial number:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="$serial" name="$serial"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$enteredSerial = $_GET['$serial'];

ob_start();
 echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<th>Order ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Product Name</th>';
    echo '<th>BCS</th>';
    echo '<th>Serial</th>';
    echo '<th>Certificate</th>';
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach( $results as $result ){

        // Html display
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->order_id . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->order_item_name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->bcs . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->serial . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $result->certificate . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
add_shortcode('greeting', 'wpb_demo_shortcode');
```